# Storing maps using JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Firstly, I apologize for the question, since I realize it has been asked a lot of times, but I couldn't get it to work.
I've been trying to store this Map in my database, but it always gives me a MappingException.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.GroupRole.class)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "user_id")
@CollectionTable(name = "group_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="group_id"))
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Long, Role.GroupRole> users = new HashMap<>();
```

The error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: groups, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(users)]
```

GroupRole is an enum. Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix this?

Comment: Apparently Hibernate is trying to generate a column for the collection. Why have you included `@Enumerated`?

Comment: I removed it but it changed nothing, the error staid the same.

Comment: Is `Role.GroupRole` an `enum`?

Answer (score 0):

if the GroupRole is assigned to the owning entity then you can use `Collections` not `Map`